# Execution failed for task ':reactive_ble_mobile:generateDebugProto'

Tags: flutter, build.gradle

I tried to run it on my android device. I am using flutter_bluetooth_serial version 0.4.0. While running the application I get the following error. the plugin does not build to Android on Windows laptop

Launching lib\main.dart on M2101K7BG in debug mode...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':reactive_ble_mobile:generateDebugProto'.

```
protoc: stdout: . stderr: C:\Users\Mustafa Y�ksel\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\reactive_ble_mobile-5.0.3\protos: warning: directory does not exist.
Could not make proto path relative: C:\Users\Mustafa Y�ksel\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\reactive_ble_mobile-5.0.3\protos\bledata.proto: No such file or directory
```

Try:

```
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BU�LD FAILED in 3m 1s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)

I get gradle error when running flutter_reactive_ble package in pubdev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem, folks. The error occurred because there were Turkish characters in the current location. I have used many packages before, but they never gave an error. I created a new user account and successfully ran the project.